# In files It wont find music!

Tags: nautilus

When I'm in Nautilus, and on the sidebar I click on Music I get an error saying "Unable to find the requested file. Please check the spelling and try again."

Comment: What do you mean by “files”? The file manager (Ubuntu uses *Nautilus* by default)? If unsure, post a screenshot.

Comment: Can you edit your question and add the output of `ls ~`? You may shorten it and remove all files (Sorry, I don't know the right switch for that). I just want to see whether there is a music-folder and how it is called...

Comment: @DavidFoerster Yes, Nautilus There is a Music tab in it, when I click on it it gives that error that I gave in the original question. Its not even a big deal, its just a small annoyance

Comment: What's the output of `grep -e '^XDG_MUSIC_DIR=' ~/.config/user-dirs.dirs` and does that folder exist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open a terminal and type the following command to fix the problem:

```
mkdir ~/Music
```

problem fixed.

It is possible you may have dragged the original Music directory into another directory so if there were any music files in that folder, just do a search for them and move them to ~/Music.